# No output voltage at transimpedance amplifier with TL081

Tags: amplifier, transimpedance

I am trying to build a transimpedance amplifier which has a input of 20uA, square wave with a frequency of 167 Hz.

My diagram looks like below but I couldn't see any output voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqLcOs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Output Voltage will be \$ i_{D1} * 1 k\Omega \$, so if you don't see an output voltage, the photocurrent is too small.

Comment: So, using Felix's equation and your data, you would expect a 167 Hz square wave with an amplitude of 2 milliVolts at the output.  You will, of course, have to use an oscilloscope to see that.

Comment: Most likely issue: TL081 does not allow rail-to-rail inputs. But without seeing your complete schematic, including power rails, we don't know for sure.

Comment: Symmetric power supplies?

Comment: If you are using an oscilloscope with 10:1 probe to observe the output, the signal is probably buried in noise.

Answer (score 1):

First, with only 20 µA of input current and a 1 kΩ feedback resistor, you would only get 20 mV of signal when everything is working right.  Are you sure you didn't?

Second, if you really aren't getting a signal out, it probably has to do with how the amplifier is powered.  The TL081 needs significant headroom at both ends of its supply range.  If you used a single ended supply with ground being the negative side, then what you have is guaranteed not to work.  Since you left off the all-important power connections, we don't know what you did, and getting into details would be pointless.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not seeing output due to a mismatch in your feedback capacitor (100nF) and the capacitance of your diode.  Since you don't give the model of the photodiode, we'll assume it is somewhere in the 4-50pF range.

The optimal size for the feedback capacitor is given by Bob Pease in [What's All This Transimpedance Amplifier Stuff Anyhow?](http://electronicdesign.com/analog/whats-all-transimpedance-amplifier-stuff-anyhow-part-1) as $$C_f=\sqrt{\frac{C_s}{GBW\times R_f}}$$

Here, $C_s$ is the *shunt* resistance of the diode.  If we assume it is 4pF (like the [Vishay TEMPD 7100](http://www.vishay.com/docs/81951/temd7000.pdf)), then using your feedback resistor of $R_f=1k\Omega$ and the TL081 gain bandwidth of 4MHz, you should be using a feedback capacitor of ~111pF.

If you want to play around with these and skip the calculations, Analog Devices has a [decent online tool](http://www.analog.com/designtools/en/photodiode/).

Comment: Unlikely.  The frequency is near DC to these cap values.  These problems are most often common mode input voltage range.

Comment: C1 and R1 have a 1.6 kHz rolloff frequency.  That really shouldn't be getting in the way of seeing a 167 Hz signal.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: Agreed.  I like your answer better.